# Unity iOS build: app store size 4x ipa size

Tags: iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store, ios9

We are facing an issue with our new game download size on the store, we are using :
- Unity 5.0.2
- Xcode 7.0.1 (bitcode disabled)

After building the game with Unity and archiving it in xCode, if we export the archive to ipa ( Save for iOS App Store Deployment , without app symbols), the ipa size is 39.4MB, but when we submit the game to App Store (through xCode organizer directly, or using the Application Loader with the ipa), Testflight shows the game size to be 172.9 MB !!!! which is a huge problem, many players will not download the game because of that.

Any help will be much appreciated.

-Khaled

Answer (score 1):

Testflight usually shows the size **including symbols**. Therefore it's important to mention that **Testflight size != Appstore size**. You can of course submit the symbols with your final Appstore submission as well, but this is not encountered for the download size limit. Apple adds some additional files to your submitted ipa but most importantly, it takes the binary and applies security measurements on the text segment which won't be compressed anymore afterwards and could increase the final size.

Anyway, you need to upgrade to a newer Unity Version, as 5.0.2 includes a quite outdated IL2CPP version which improved a lot in the last year. There is a guide on how to receive proper values and also some tips in the Unity forums about it.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-build-size-improvements.322079/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem! Just move back to xcode 6.4 version! :)

Comment: And in any case, this isn't a good long-term solution. If history is any indicator, Apple will soon start requiring apps to be submitted using XCode 7.